# Form-Based Authentication WAS 8.5

Tags: authentication, websphere

I am trying to implement Form-based authentication on IBM webSphere WAS v8.5, but for some reasons the security configurations are ignored and i can access all protect resources without being redirected to the login page below are my declarative security configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>TestSSO</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
 <security-role>
    <role-name>manager</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>management pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
     <security-role name="manager">
     <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
     </security-role>

</application-bnd>
```

Comment: Is security enabled on the server?

Comment: Seeing your comments below, this would probably mean that you already are authenticated. An easy test is to actually write out the user name or something similar. That way you know if you are authenticated or not.

Comment: I tried accessing using chrome instead of IE and it gives me the login page, i logged in and everything works ok, but i closed the browser to retest and the same very first problem security is ignored and i can access the protected resource without authentication

Comment: You may have configured authentication via the operating system that logs you in automatically without you knowing it. If you are running Windows and IE you may have automatic login (with the correct configured in WAS) but in Chrome it might not be configured by default. This could explain the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but how can i know if this is the case (authentication via the operating system that logs you in automatically without you knowing it), cause if i restart my PC and try i got the login page only for the first time, then i got back to the same case "security is ignored"

Comment: From time to time I have used a small application which is configured to only allowe authenticated users and all it does is to print out the user's user id.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one protected resource defined, namely `/index.html`. Adjust `<url-pattern>` to include all resources you need to protect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do Role mapping using WebSphere console. It's to map the user groups from User repository to the

Answer (score -1):

This should be your `ibm-application-bnd.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
     <security-role name="manager">
        <group name="manager" />
     </security-role>

</application-bnd>
```

Comment: That would only be valid if there is a security group named manager. In this case there is already a mapping between the role and the users that should be part of that role.

Comment: I did this, and now it gives me HTTP 403 forbidden instead of redirecting me to login page

Comment: Yes it show will 403 forbidden if user authenticated but not authorized to access resource. It will redirect to login page only if user is not authenticated. So you can add self redirect on 403 page.

Comment: but i did not enter any credentials, how did it know that i am authenticated? i need the user to be redirected to the login page upon requesting a protected resource

Comment: Do you have SSO configured with other servers?

Comment: Not till now, actually i want to make a POC of implementing SSO using SMAL support in WebSphere WAS 8.5. i started by trying to implement a sample form based authentication application to be able to proceed with my POC but i am still stuck here. the error i get is SECJ0129E: Authorization failed for user wasadmin1:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm while invoking GET on default_host:TestSSO/index.html, Authorization failed, Not granted any of the required roles: manager, although i mapped the user to the group using the WAS admin consoul

Comment: I tried accessing using chrome instead of IE and it gives me the login page, i logged in and everything works ok, but i closed the browser to retest and the same very first problem security is ignored and i can access the protected resource without authentication