# Form-based authentication in WebSphere with J2C Connection factory

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jaas

I'm totally confused trying to configur security in my WebSphere Web-application.

I'm required to make smth like:
Form based authentication + JAAS + J2C Connection (custom J2C adaptor, which goes to some specific LDAP server). As I've understood I'm not allowed to use this LDAP server straightforward.

I'm using WebSphere 8.5.

I configured "Form based authentication" similar to this post: [Form-Based Authentication WAS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902419/form-based-authentication-was-8-5) . And it works when switching on "Global security" with test realm storing users/roles in prop-files.

I also succeeded to configure J2C adapter (at least I hope so).

I just can't understand how can I put it all together. I'm looking at "Security domains" instead of "Global security" but I can't imaging the way to bind my application with created security domain.

Also under "My security domain" -> "JAAS J2C Authentication Data" I see two aliases: one is already in use for MQ and the second one is the one I'm interested in at the moment. How can I tell my application to use this exact alias, not the wrong one?

Would appreciate any help or link...

UPDATED answering to question from comment (don't have right to comment yet). And once more here:
 * I have to use custom J2C connector, that is already provided to me as RAR-archive.
 * By "using of JAAS" I mean firstly that from the side of application I should use only J2EE standard stuff. But probablty I will reach this goal simply by using "form-based authentication"...
 * *do you just want to use alias with J2C?* I need to think about it more... don't really understand your question at the moment(

Comment: This needs some more clarification. Do you want to use LDAP as your user registry? (Then you should just configure LDAP repository in the federated registry). What kind of J2C adapter are you using?(custom?) What for you need JAAS? (do you just want to use alias with J2C? Then you should be able to specify it in the J2C connection factory as authentication alias).

Comment: Any specific reason why you are not allowed to use standard LDAP registry configuration provided with WebSphere via Federated repository? You have to elaborate a bit more what this custom J2C connector is doing, how it should be used by application and why it is required.